# Wordpress load-scripts.php (Failed to load resource)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Been experiencing this error which causes my Wordpress Admin Panel to malfunction especially in Media File uploading. For files more than 1MB, the uploading does not continue, loading bar disappears instantly upon selecting the image to be uploaded.

Certain error occurred when:
 1. I have updated to v 4.7.2.
 2. Hardcoded site_url() to url in script-loader.php
 3. Re-started the server several times.

Please see attached image. This is the 
[error provided by console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Tdg.png.)

Can you guys suggest anything for me to do? I don't know already what is causing this error. Thank you!

EDIT:

I am using IIS Server.

Comment: did you enable debugging in wp-config file? might provide more information.

Comment: okay. thanks. i will.